# Gabor features extraction for detecting people

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I am currently doing people detection using HOG, LBP and Gabor as feature extractions. However, when i used gabor feature extraction, the detection takes long time, though accuracy is high. I am implementing gabor feature extraction code from here:

[Gabor feature extraction](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46790-gabor-wavelets)

I am using a SVM as classifier to determine whether the object is people or not. My question is how to speed the processing in MATLAB, in order to avoid long and slow processing. Or hopefully someone have mex file for Gabor feature extraction, so that I could try to implement it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As of R2015b release, you can create a Gabor filter bank using the [gabor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gabor.html) function in the image processing toolbox, and you can apply it to an image using [imgaborfilt](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html). These functions may speed things for you.